# macos disable power cpu throttling

Tags: macos, battery

I have a faulty battery in my Macbook Pro. Battery status is stuck at 2% and shows as "no charging".

I believe this is causing my CPU to be throttled, `pmset -g thermlog` outputs this:

```
Note: No thermal warning level has been recorded
Note: No performance warning level has been recorded
CPU Power notify
    CPU_Scheduler_Limit     = 100
    CPU_Available_CPUs  = 8
    CPU_Speed_Limit     = 50
```

Since the battery is already dead, I just want to either disable the battery or disable the throttling feature.

Is there a way to do this via software? I know I can probably open the laptop and unplug the battery but want to first try a software alternative.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It makes sense that the machine will throttle if the battery is dead, because the charger is not capable of delivering on-demand high power throughput - that's the battery's job.
The fix is… a new battery.

I don't know whether this is technically bypassable, but if you do, then whenever high power is required, the mac will just hard-crash.

Comment: Sorry you mean that the charger can't feed 100% this laptop?

Comment: No. The charger's job is to charge the battery, not run the computer. It is not capable of powering the computer under high load. Hence the computer will reduce its potential load by backing off processor speeds, GPU power etc, to avoid crashing hard.

Comment: Got it thanks. I'll try to unplug it and see how far it can go. Right now it's sluggish as hell.

Comment: If the battery is dying, then the machine will throttle back just the same.

Comment: A dead battery is the same as unplugging the battery. You won't see any difference.